# Amount of combinations with nominals given

Tags: python, recursion, combinations

I am to calculate the amount of combinations of a number (let's call it C) using N numbers given.
I am to use a recursive formula.
However there is an error:
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType' "
My code:

```
def amount(N, C, latest_nominal = 0):
    if C < 0:
        return print("C should be positive")
    if C == 0:
        return print("1")
    if not N:
        return print("There are no nominals")
    possibilities = 0
    for nominal in N:
        if nominal >= latest_nominal:
            possibilities += amount(N, C-nominal, nominal)
    return possibilities
```

I would appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `print()` function returns `None`.

So when you do `return print("C should be positive")`, you are returning None. Hence, at the line `possibilities += amount(N, C-nominal, nominal)` your code is raising Exception

Comment: Thank you! How can I avoid that problem?